# What is the token identifier of `]`?

Tags: bash

Bash Manual says:

> When the [ form is used, the last argument to the command must be a ].

```
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
$ type ]
bash: type: ]: not found
```

So `]` isn't a reserved word, nor is it an operator, nor is it a builtin command.

As a token, what is the token identifier of `]`? WORD or NAME?

Comment: Actually, `[` is (also) a self-sustained command:   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39552 Dec  3 18:14 /usr/bin/[   Though it's possible there is also "parallel" built-in, like there is for for example `kill`.  On some system, the `test` command is a symbolic link to `[` or vice versa.  AFAIK, `]` doesn't mean anything by itself, but is accepted to "close" a `[` - but it's more for "aesthetic" reason.

Comment: The shell language has grown layer by layer over the past 46 years, and internal consistency was never a priority.  If you try to force-fit it into any sort of theoretical formal-language framework you are going to have a bad time.

Comment: Since `[` is (also) a self-contained command, it usually got a man-page... So try `man [` and/or `man test` (`[` and `test` may be the same command).

Comment: Try sticking the `]` in single or double quotes and you will see it makes no difference; it's just a string.

Answer (score 21):

`]` complements `[`, it is the closing sign of `[` command.

As the `man` page points out, this is actually an argument to `[`, but `[` happens to treat it especially, as the ending.

You can resemble it with some other command closing patterns, for example `;` in `find .. exec`.

Comment: Thanks. What is the token type/identifier of `]`?

Comment: @Tim `]` is no different from any other normal character in this context (as an argument to a command). The `test` command treats it specially, but that's up to the command.

Comment: It's just a string, and `[` raises an error if its final argument isn't exactly equal to `]`.

Answer (score 19):

Bash does not treat the `[` or `]` characters (on their own) any different from a letter of the alphabet.

In this case bash sees a "word", `[`, and goes looking for a command with that name. If you look in your filesystem you'll probably find that `/bin/[` (or `/usr/bin/[`) exists as an executable file. As it happens, bash also provides a built in version (for the sake of efficiency), but that's just an implementation detail.

The `[` command (as in, the executable with that name), has a rule that the last parameter you pass to it should be `]` or else it throws an error. This may be partly because it's aesthetically pleasing, but it also serves to protect you from accidentally truncated commands, which is nice.

The fact that these are *not special* is why you can't omit the white space before and after the `[` or `]`.

---

**Exceptions**:

- When `[` and `]` occur in the correct format within the same word, e.g. `[a-z]`, then that *is* special and bash's globbing rules apply.
- The `[[` command *is* special and can do many things `[` cannot (and parameters inside `[[ .. ]]` are processed differently, as are some line breaks). The corresponding `]]` is also special, as it is a shell reserved word that cannot be a command name, and terminates the special processing that follows the `[[` keyword.

Comment: @JacobKrall It's not a special character like `;` or `>`, it's just a built-in command like `cd`. In particular, if you type `[x`, the `[` has no special meaning.

Comment: @JacobKrall That's true for all built-in commands. `[` is a special **command**, it's not a special **character**.

Comment: @Barmar: Fair enough; I retract my comments.

Comment: Actually `]]` is more special than `]`. When using `[` and `]` they are just words. If you omitted `]` or replaced it with a different word, bash will still run `[`, but `[` will produce an error. However `[[` and `]]` are treated special at parsing time. If you replaced `]]` with something else, bash will report a syntax error. And if you omitted `]]` bash would keep parsing the next line looking for the `]]`.

Comment: @kasperd answer adjusted.

Comment: Nice for spelling out why the white space is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

To put it more simply than the previous two answers, `]` is just a string that `[` requires to run.

Comment: This seems a bit like a comment...

Comment: @wizzwizz4, given the followup questions from the OP in comments, I think this simplicity is exactly what he needed.

Comment: @Wildcard I actually agree. There was something tempting me to upvote this answer, but I thought it was low quality. (Didn't downvote though!) I'm going to edit to improve the markup.